# Repair loop wiring?

Tags: electrical

I have a situation where there is a poor connection in the loop wire, I can fix the connection, but there is not enough room for the 3-way switch plus the yellow or orange wire caps (3 repaires/3 caps)

The old 3-way switch (about 60 years old) is much smaller then the new 3-way switch. The old wire was very brittle and broke off at the switch, so I had to add some new #12 to the old wire to make it long enough to rewire to the switch.  I'd send a comparison pic, but the old switch came apart when I removed it.

Comment: do you have an actual question?

Comment: Welcome back.  What do you mean by "loop wire"?  Switch loop?

Comment: Downstairs & Upstairs wall switches controlling upstairs kit fixture.

Comment: The downstairs switch has gone bad and it is smaller then the 3 way switches available now.

Comment: Yes, my question is - does anyone know of a smaller 3-way wall switch and/or does anyone know of a method of capping/splicing new to old wires without using the yellow (large) caps?

Comment: In my original post - I was attempting to present a problem/question with the hope of getting a resolve to my problem.

Comment: In really old construction wiremold box extenders can give you the extra room you need, there are several models, [like this,](https://homedepot.app.link/SeNs1mdOsK) just be sure to get the open back extender, not the flat back self contained.

Comment: Thanks for the link - looks like a possibility - how does it attache to the current box?

Comment: On taking another look - it appears the installation has it sticking/protruding out from the wall - unfortunately in this case, due to the condition of the wall (plaster).   I need to find either a smaller switch or smaller method of new to old.  I'm thinking of push terminals, but mot sure how they work.

Comment: @Tyson good call.  OP those bolt to the same two screws that the switch currently bolts into.  They do not tie to the plaster/drywall/cinderblock at all.

Comment: @SHQueens I've lived in an old old house once.  You can get a standard switch in similar size to what you took out.  You won't find a dimmer or smart switch (your yellow and orange wires are the giveaway).  I had a couple locations that got updated via the wiremold extenders, once it's in place you don't "see" it--it just blends in.  If the actual wall condition is crumbling that's an easy repair too.

Comment: The orange & yellow are not the wires, there the caps.  The wires have the cloth type covering.

Comment: From where can I get a similar size switch as the old one?

Comment: Does anyone know about Push Wire Connectors? They may be a solution to the space problem.

Comment: In follow-up, the Push-In wire connectors worked well, they took half the room of the caps, I was able to install the new switch.